# Get the measure M along a CircularStringM in PostGIS without first converting to a LineStringM

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, linear-referencing, true-curves, circularstring

I've been struggling to get PostGIS 2.5 to run any linear referencing functions on geometry containing curves (CircularStringM, CompoundCurveM for example).  Is it possible to get the measure M along a CircularStringM in PostgreSQL/PostGIS without first converting it to a LineStringM?  LineStringM isn't accurate enough to represent the curve for the specific application I'm working on.

Looking to get the closest PointM along a CompoundCurveM or CircularStringM from a user-added point some distance away.  Too bad ST_ClosestPoint doesn't support PointM and Curves.

Willing to settle for a python solution that works nicely with PostGIS.